# How to replace indexes by values from different list?

Tags: python

I have two lists:

```
test_list1 = [2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 4] 
test_list2 = [[1, 5], [4, 2, 3], [0]]
```

I want to replace the indexes in `test_list2` by the values in `test_list1` such that the result would be:

```
[[3, 4], [2, 4, 5], [2]]
```

I have tried this:

```
res = [test_list1[idx] for idx in test_list2]
```

I have notice that my code only works for a list without sublists

Comment: `[[test_list1[i] for i in sublist] for sublist in test_list2]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A oneliner with list comprehension and map function could look like this:

```
test_list1 = [2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 4]
test_list2 = [[1, 5], [4, 2, 3], [0]]

output = list(map(lambda x: [test_list1[y] for y in x], test_list2))

print(output)
# [[3, 4], [2, 4, 5], [2]]
```

Comment: Or write as nested list comprehensions `[[test_list1[y] for y in x] for x in test_list2]` or nested `list(map(...))` as `list(map(lambda x: list(map(test_list1.__getitem__, x)), test_list2))`

Comment: Then I guess the last combination is `[list(map(test_list1.__getitem__, x)) for x in test_list2]` :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a recursive function. This will go through an arbitarily nested list, replacing the values.

```
def replace(lst, replacements):
    for i, val in enumerate(lst):
        if isinstance(val, list):
            replace(val, replacements)
        else:
            lst[i] = replacements[val]

            
test_list1 = [2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 4]
test_list2 = [[1, 5], [4, 2, 3], [0]]

replace(test_list2, test_list1)
print(test_list2)
```

Gives:

```
[[3, 4], [2, 4, 5], [2]]
```

Comment: But is this the right result? I mean the last obj in test_list2 for example is 0 and for index 0 the inserted number should be 2 and not 4. Or am I getting the question wrong?

Comment: @MisterNox Okay, looks like I've misunderstood the question. I'll delete this in a moment while I have a think about it...

Comment: @MisterNox Now corrected (it was solving a rather different problem) -- thanks again for pointing that out.

Comment: No problem, just wanted to make sure that I did not get it wrong. In terms of learning new techniques and finding different ways to get to your goals it is an interesting soltion as well.